# Safe way to retrieve and transfer User-Id across CakePHP

Tags: cakephp

I am CakeNoob so please accept my sincere apologies for this question.

After users Added their account in my Webapp, they are redirected to users/view where they can see their account details and edit them.

From here, there are links to achievement/add where people can add achievements to their profile. The User and Achievement model are nicely coupled through belongsTo and HasMany associations. Once a user adds an Achievement, it will be displayed in the users/view page via related Achievements.

Problem: Once I manually add an Achievement through achievements/add (and select the current user from the list(all)), it works fine.

But I want that achievements can only be added when users come from users/view, so I need to transport the user-id to achievements/add and then tell Cake that this is the user-id (foreign key) to use.

- All users are logged in once they reach users/view so I guess the Auth session may help me.

I have tried many things but my knowledge is just too minor to solve this. Your solutions are appreciated!! Thanks

Comment: Which server programming language do you use?

Answer (score 0):

if you use "Auth" to register and login, you can use $this->Auth->user('id'); to get the user id throughout your application

Comment: thanks, How can I add this User-id to $this->data in my controller to save it into the database?

Comment: `$this->data['id'] = $this->Auth->user('id');`

Answer (score 0):

You can save it with:

```
$this->data['User']['id'] = $this->Auth->user('id');
$this->User->save($this->data);
```